# How can I get the value of the selected item from igcombo

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, igcombo

I need to get value of the selected item from igcombo to use in an `if` condition to show and hide a panel.

```js
function GetPerfType() {
  var BEFilteJSon = {};
  BEFilteJSon.SVC_FEE_TYPE_ID = $("#SVC_FEE_TYPE_ID").igCombo("value");
  var json = "{'filterObj' : '" + JSON.stringify(BEFilteJSon);
  json += "'}";
  var data = callAjaxMethod("GetFeesData", json);
  var IS_PER = data[0].IS_PERFORMANCE_FEES_TYPE;
  if (IS_PER == "Y") {
    $("#YES").show();
  } else {
    $("#YES").hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Post callAjaxMethod or create fiddler or codepen because you have put the whole scenario but not the actual problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Calling:

`$('selector').igCombo('value');`

will return:

- empty array if nothing is selected;
- in single selection igCombo the value of the property assigned to `valueKey` of the selected item. For example if you have set for your igCombo `valueKey` to `id` and `textKey` to `name`, if selected item has this data `{id: 56, name: 'USA'}` `value` will return 56.
- in multiple selection igCombo an array of all values of all selected item related to the value key. Same as in single selection but array of values. If you have same setup and selected items are `{id: 56, name: 'USA'}` and `{id: 23, name: 'Canada'}` `value` will return `[56, 23]`.